# Is memory allocated once or at every instantiation of Objects in java

Tags: java, memory

I made a little program to hold my X and Y values. here is my code:

```
public class ChartData 
    {
        private Object x, y; 

        public ChartData(Object x, Object y)
        {
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;
        }

        public Object getX() 
        {
            return x;
        }

        public Object getY() 
        {
            return y;
        }

        public boolean equals(Object obj)
        {
            if (obj != null && obj instanceof ChartData) 
            {
                final ChartData other = (ChartData) obj;
                if (this.getX().equals(other.getX()) && this.y == null && other.y == null) 
                {
                    return true;
                }
                else if (this.getX().equals(other.getX()) && this.y.equals(other.y)) 
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }
            return false;
        }

        public int hashCode()
        {
            int hashCode = getX().hashCode();
            hashCode = (y != null) ? hashCode + y.hashCode() : hashCode ;
            return hashCode;
        }
    }
```

I would like to sum the values of the ChartData Object(ie it holds X and Y values).
For Example:-

```
LinkedHashMap<ChartData, Object> datasource = new LinkedHashMap<ChartData, Object>();
        while(data.next())
        {            
            Object x = data.getValue(1);
            Object y = data.getValue(2);
            Double value = data.getValue(3);
            ChartData cateVal = new ChartData(x, y);
            Double currentValue = (Double) datasource.get(cateVal);
            if(currentValue != null)
            {
                datasource.put(cateVal, currentValue + value);
            }
            else
            {
                datasource.put(cateVal, value);
            }
        }
```

there is a chance to create a new object for the same X and Y values.Is it actually creates a new object for every instantiation or else it uses previously created memory.Please explain me.

Comment: I believe that every time you call `new Xxxx()` a new object is created on the heap. Now if your only reference to this object is a HashMap, and if it is equivalent to another object already on the HashMap, then my intuition tells me that only one object will reside on the Map, and the other will be available for garbage collection should/when the need arises.

Answer (score 1):

You HashMap key, i.e, `ChartData cateVal = new ChartData(x, y);` creates a new object everytime 
it is called.

There is no automatic memory management, and I don't think there is any way to overcome this using HashMaps, but you should not worry about it, creation of such objects is very cheap.

I don't know if it is possible in general to get a mapping from (X, Y) -> Z, where X and Y are arbitrary
objects, without creating an object that holds (X, Z). Maps in Java are from a single object to object. If X and Y are integers, or can be mapped to integers, you can create an array Z[][] indexed by X and Y. In you case it would mean that x and y inside CharData should be integers, which I assume what you want:

```
Object z = datasource[x][y];
if (z == null) {
    z = new ChartData(x,y);
    datasource[x][y] = z;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Ali. Is there any chance to reduce the Object creation?

Comment: If x and y can be large the array will eat up a lot of space.

Comment: @user949300 that's true, and there is another downside to arrays: for initializing `datasource`, the maximum values should be known. But I guess that's the only way to avoid creation of objects for hashmap lookup.

Comment: @Ali see my answer for the sparse case.  I like yours better if the max values are known and small.

Answer (score 1):

If the x and y values are sparse and possibly large, a better approach than the 2D array is needed.

Consider a `Map<Integer, Map<Integer, ChartData>>` as your cache.  **Very** Skeleton code:

```
Map ymap = xmap.get(theXCoordinate);
if (ymap != null)
   chartData = ymap.get(theYCoordinate);
```

If chartData is there, return it, else add to the cache creating and putting the inner map if needed.

**Note**: unless you have a lot of duplicate ChartDatas, this probably uses more memory than just creating the duplicates.  Exercise left for the reader as to where is the cutoff for now.  :-)

**v2**:  Another idea I thought of later:

Create a `Long` holding your x and y coordinates, and use that as the key into a `Map<Long, ChartData>`.  If your xs and ys are usually small, you could test that they are both less than 2^16 and use an `Integer` instead.

Comment: This is interesting. I guess the only draw back of this approach is to check for nulls, and initiliazing the empty map.